# Why $x^2+2y^2=22$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis

For the set $$S=\left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+2y^2=22 \right \}$$ this is an ellipse and it looks like this:
[image: Ellipse]

I need to show that it is compact which means it is bounded and closed.
What is formal way to show compactness?

Comment: One note, compact does NOT mean closed and bounded! The Heine-Borel theorem gives us that closed and bounded is equivalent to compact for finite Euclidean spaces. Compact by definition means that every open cover can be reduced to a finite open cover. Very different!(and applies to more general topological spaces where compact isn't the same thing as closed and bounded.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As $f(x,y) = x^2 + 2y^2$ is a continuous function, the preimage $S = f^{-1}(\{22\})$ of the closed set $\{22\}$ is closed by continuity.

Furthermore, if $x^2 + 2y^2 = 22$, then $\|(x,y)\|^2 = x^2 + y^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 + y^2 = 22$, so the set $S$ is bounded by $\sqrt{22}$. That is $(x,y) \in S \Rightarrow \|(x,y)\| \leq \sqrt 22$.

This is a standard real-analysis problem and practicing this type of problem might score some easy points on an exam.

Comment: "Might score some easy points on an exam", I thought we were supposed to solve all the problems in an exam.

Comment: @dREaM I think he meant that if you study this and a related problem ends up on the exam(which there is a decent chance of since it is a standard problem) then the studying you did will allow you to easily and quickly get full credit for this question and allow you more time for other questions on the exam.

Answer (score 6):

**Bounded:**
Taking $s=(x,y)\in S$, one has 
$\lVert s \rVert^2 = x^2 + y^2 \leq x^2 + 2y^2 = 22$.

**Closed:** The function $f\colon (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto x^2 + 2y^2$ is continuous, and $\{22\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ (can you see why both these statements hold?). Therefore, $S = f^{-1}(\{22\})$ is closed.

Comment: What about $x^2 + y^2 \geq 2$?

Comment: You mean, the set $T = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\colon x^2+y^2\geq 2\}$? It is closed (define the right function and closed set in $\mathbb{R}$). Do you think it is bounded?

Comment: Yeah ... it seems it is not bounded but I am not sure about closeness

Comment: Consider the preimage of the closed set $[2,\infty)$ by the continuous function $f\colon (x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Since $f:(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto x^2 + y^2$ is continuous and $S=f^{-1}([2,\infty))$ is closed?

Comment: Yes -- that's the same argument as for the original question.

Answer (score 1):

$S = f^{-1}[\{22\}]$ for a suitable continuous function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which makes it closed.

Can $|x| > 10$ or $|y| > 10$ occur?  If not (prove it), boundedness follows....

Answer (score 1):

Consider the disk $x^2+y^2\leq 22$. Clearly it contains that elipse, so the elipse is bounded.

To see it is closed note that $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$ is a continuous function, so the pre-image of the closed set $\{22\}$ is closed.